# Qt mouseEvent and widget

Tags: qt

I want to know which widget was pressed on the app windows. To do this, I use the mousePressEvent function, but it is not exactly what I want.

> void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
>
> QLabel* child= static_cast(this->childAt(event->pos()));
>
> ```
> if(!child)
>   return;
> ```
>
> }

First of all, for labels, I'm using the above code. However, child is never "null", so it always skips if statement during pressing anywhere except a label widget on it.

By the way, I thought that maybe there can be a label on the screen, and I have just checked this. as a result I have seen an unusual situation that there is a label altough no labels are used. (it's not only label widget, the situation is always the same with other widget.).

Let me show how to realize this, I have checked child's witdh and visibility, the width changes with the window's size and visibility is always TRUE during pressing anywhere on it.

> ```
> qDebug() << "child width =" <<child->width() ;
> qDebug() << "isEnabled =" <<QString::number(child->isEnabled()) ;
> ```

The output during pressing the empty area:

> child width = 400 isEnabled = "1" child width = 721 isEnabled = "1"
>   child width = 1059 isEnabled = "1"

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If you need to identify whether the clicked object is a `QLabel`, you can try to cast the child to it: `QLabel * childLabel = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(this->childAt(event->pos())); if (!childLabel) { return; }`

Comment: Are you trying to find which element triggered the event? Question not clear.